# Linking an Actiontec router and a Synology router

Tags: router

My Verizon FiOS connection is an old one, using COAX cable from the ONT to a  Verizon-provided  Actiontec M1424WR Rev I Router.  I just ordered a Synology RT2600AC router which, I have been informed, provides far better security than does the Actiontec and is much more configurable.  Because the connection to the Actiontec is via COAX, I have to keep the Actiontec router.  The more I research how to manage the settings in both routers, the more confused I become.  Some instructions indicate it is easy; others are bafflingly complex and involve DMZ settings, netmasks, non-routable subnets, etc.  I am beginning to worry that I have bitten off way more than I can chew (my wife is sure I have ;-).

Does anyone have the knowledge and patience to point me in the right direction and if so, many thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su].